# GridView error when I try to read, show items information from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview

I get this error:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'updateform_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'updateform_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 49:                 </div>
Line 50:             </div>
Line 51:         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
Line 52:         </asp:GridView>
Line 53:     </form>
```

This is where I try to show information on GridView:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-62V61RT\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog =ShopOnlineDB; Integrated Security=True;");
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Master.Items", con);

SqlDataAdapter dat = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dat.Fill(dt);

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: The error is quite clear: you don't have a GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged event handler method defined in your code.

Comment: A SQL Command has four types 1) Select 2) Insert 3) Update 4) Delete.  You have only the select and need the Update.  Use a Command Builder to create thoe other three from the select : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in the code in cs file

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       // you code
}
```